# Improve a Google API Call

Tags: python-3.x, google-places-api

I wrote a function for calls to the Google Places API, but I would like to make it better. Specifically, I suspect there is a better way to handle optional arguments such as `location` and `radius` in the function call. How can I construct my url dynamically without writing all of the possible permutations of optional arguments?

```
def get_data(query,api_key,radius=None,location=None):
    if location==None and radius==None:
    url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=%s&fields=name,formatted_address,opening_hours,price_level,rating&key=%s" % (query,api_key)
    elif location is not None:
    url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=%s&location=%s&fields=name,formatted_address,opening_hours,price_level,rating&key=%s" % (query,location, api_key)
    elif location is not None and radius is not None:
     url="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=%s&location=%s&radius=%s&fields=name,formatted_address,opening_hours,price_level,rating&key=%s" % (query,location,radius, api_key)

----Snip-----
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this code would solve your problem:

```
base_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?'
params = {
    'key': 'api_key', 
    'fields':'name,formatted_address,opening_hours,price_level,rating',
    'query' : query
}

if location is not None:
    params['location'] = location 
if radius is not None:
    params['radius'] = radius
    url = base_url + urllib.urlencode(params)
```